# Submitting HTML Forms with Slider as input (WebFX)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I submit the value of [this slider](http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/slider/slider.html) to a CGI application (like you would a check box)?
Not sure if the input tag for the slider is messing something up?

```
<div class="slider" id="slider-1" tabIndex="1">
   <input class="slider-input" id="slider-input-1"
      name="slider-input-1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Think i am getting closer. Created a button and am passing the value with an on click event <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn" onclick="sub_slide(s.getValue())">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it:

```
            <form action="/cgi-bin/Lib.exe" method=POST name="slider" ID="Form2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="" ID="Text1">
            </form>  

<input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn" onclick="setval()" onmouseover="hov(this, 'btn btnhov')" onmouseout="hov(this, 'btn')" ID="Button1" NAME="Button1"/>

function setval()
{   
    //alert(s.getValue());
    document.slider.user.value = s.getValue();//set value of hidden text box to value of slider
    document.slider.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd try tweaking the `<input>` tag's `type` attribute, setting it to `text` or `hidden`.

(I don't know enough about the framework/environment you're using to say for sure.)